# Enabling plugin on specific pages and subpages

Tags: plugins, pages, javascript, scripts

To increase the loading speed, I would like to only enable Event Manager plugin on the pages where it's actually used. For that, I wrote this piece of code:

```
// deregister unnecessary plugin scripts:
function my_deregister() {
    if ( !is_page('events') ) { 
        wp_deregister_script( 'events-manager' ); 
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister', 100 );
```

However, the problem is that this event plugin creates a single page for each event and it needs to be enabled on those sub-pages, too. Apparently, each generated page is named differently. For instance, **www.mysite.com/events/EventNameEventDate**.

So I would like to have the plugin disabled on all pages except for 'events' and its sub-pages (of which I will obviously not always know the count and names). The **is_page()** works fine for the Events page but how do I modify it so that it recognises its sub-pages and enables the plugin scripts on them, too?

*This was just a plugin specific example for easier understanding of the problem, but the question is generic and plugin independent.*

Comment: Try like **is_singular( 'events' )** for single pages

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work @PratikPatel

Comment: **events** is a **custom post type** right ?

Comment: It might be smarter to turn it around, so so it's easier to maintain. You can hook into enqueue scripts, deregister the s cript be default and only enqueue it where it's needed.

Comment: @PratikPatel **Events** is a regular page and its subpages are generated by the plugin so not sure what it is to be honest.

Comment: @JeffreyvonGrumbkow I think I see what you are trying to say, but still how would I target those subpages even if it was the other way around? as **is_page()** is not working for them

Comment: You should debug this part in  functions.php just write simple code to check what is_page or is_single functions etc are actually triggered in de places where you need them to to igure out exactly what code to use

Answer (score 0):

You can get parent page slug and check like

```
global $post;
$post_data = get_post($post->post_parent);
$parent_slug = $post_data->post_name;
//echo $parent_slug;
if ( !is_page('events') || $parent_slug != 'events') {
```

Please try and let me know if any query

Answer (score 0):

As Pratik Patel said in one if his comments. You can use `is_singular( 'custom_post_type_name' )` to filter on CPT pages.

Since you are using Events Manager see this file from their plugin:
https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/events-manager/trunk/em-posts.php
On line 3 you see they define their CPT name as `event`.
So in your case you can use `is_singular('event')`

```
// deregister unnecessary plugin scripts:
function my_deregister() {
    if ( ! is_page('events') && ! is_singular('event') ) { 
        wp_deregister_script( 'events-manager' ); 
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister', 100 );
```